Handling HTTPS Proxy Authentication in Android Emulator with Python
My goal is to configure a proxy with authorization for an Android emulator (used with Appium) launched from command line.
I tried configuring the Android emulator directly with a proxy via this command:
emulator -avd <device> -http-proxy 'http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>'

Or setting in Android Studio settings
But I face the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED issue for HTTPS traffic.
Most solutions on internet handle this without the proxy auth.
So a solution is to remove authorization from proxy by setting up local upstream proxy to the actual proxy with auth.
In Node.js, I achieved this with the proxy-chain library using the following code:
const { anonymizeProxy } = require('proxy-chain');

(async () => {
    const proxy = 'http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>';
    const anonymizedProxy = await anonymizeProxy(proxy);
    console.log(anonymizedProxy);
})();

This setup worked perfectly, handling HTTP and HTTPS traffic without issues. I tried  to replicate this behavior in Python using pproxy library with the following code:
import asyncio
import pproxy

async def main():
    local_server = 'http://0.0.0.0:1234'
    upstream_proxy = 'http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>'

    server = pproxy.Server(local_server)
    remote = pproxy.Connection(upstream_proxy)
    args = {'rserver': [remote]}

    await server.start_server(args)
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

asyncio.run(main())

It works for HTTPS as system proxy inside my browser, but for emulator I still see ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error for HTTPS requests.
I do not need any traffic inspection just forwarding to the real proxy.
Is it possible to achieve this in Python? Are there libraries similar to proxy-chain for Python? Or is there a way to properly configure the Android emulator to use an authenticated proxy? Any insights would be appreciated!

You might get better responses if you detail what operating system and version you are using and which version of Python you would like to use.
